# jQuery one function not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jsp

I have the following jsp:

```
...
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

    // prevent multiple submissions
    $('#saveCallListBtn').one("click", function() {
        $('#callListForm').submit();
    });

});

...
</script>
...
<form:form id="callListForm" commandName="callList" action="${contextPath}/calllist/save" method="POST" htmlEscape="true">

...

<td colspan="2" style="text-align: center">
    <input id="saveCallListBtn" type="submit" value="Save" class="button-med"/>
</td>

...

</form:form>
```

The behavior I am looking for is to only all the form to be submitted once no matter how many times the save button is clicked. Using the jQuery .one function, I can get the above code to correctly work. As the form will submit multiple times if I click more than once.

The following code will work fine:

```
$('#saveCallListBtn').on("click", function() {
        $(this).prop("disabled", true);
        $('#callListForm').submit();
    });
```

But I am interested to know what I am doing wrong with the .one function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note the `type` here:

```
<input id="saveCallListBtn" type="submit" value="Save" class="button-med"/>
```

A `submit` button in a `form` will submit the form, no JavaScript required. So when your handler is automatically removed, on the next click the default handling (submitting the form) occurs, courtesy of the browser.

The only reason you're not seeing the form submitted *twice* on first click, I suspect, is that the act of submitting the form begins the process of tearing down the page to make room for the result of the submission.

---

FWIW, I would suggest that you *not* have a `click` handler on the button, but rather a `submit` handler on the form that, if all is well and it's going to allow submission to occur, disables the button and sets a flag to prevent future form submission, since forms can be submitted in multiple ways. (On some forms, pressing Enter in a text field will do it, for instance.)

E.g.:

```
$("#callListForm").on("submit", function(e) {
    var $btn = $("#saveCallListBtn");
    var valid = !$btn.prop("disabled");
    if (valid) {
        // ...do any other validity checks you may want, set `valid` to false
        // if problems encountered...
    }
    if (valid) {
        $btn.prop("disabled", true);
    } else {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery `one` function will execute the *event handler* only once. However, the default behaviour of the element clicked will execute indefinitely.

Change the type of the button to `button`, such that it has no default behaviour:

```
<input id="saveCallListBtn" type="button" value="Save" class="button-med"/>
```